# Can i use self-signed certificate for Uber webhook endpoint in sandbox?

Tags: uber-api

I am setting up a webhook URL for Uber API integration. It is mandatory to use 'https'. For testing i am using a self-signed certificate but the callbacks from uber server are not hitting my endpoint. Do i need to get a real certificate just for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We require a valid ssl certificate in order to receive a webhook. The great news is you can easily setup an ssl certificate for free with letsenrypt. Find out more at https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/.

Get started at https://certbot.eff.org/

Comment: Thanks, looks like the right solution. I will try that.